# External Interface Error

Tags: javascript, flash, constants, externalinterface

This is the code I am using to call a function `calc` in javascript:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.addCallback("asFunc", this, asFunc); 

function asFunc(str:String):Void {
    out.text = "JS > Hello " + str;
}

send_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener);

function clickListener(eventObj:Object):Void {
    trace("click > " + mean.text);
    ExternalInterface.call("calc", mean.text);
}
```

but I get the following error:

> 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Void.

What am I doing wrong here? (I modified the example on live docs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Void should be lower-case.

Like this:

```
void
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks (by your error) like you have a couple of problems here:

1. ExternalInterface takes two arguments in AS3, not three
2. "Void" should be "void" in AS3

So assuming your JavaScript code were something like this:

```
function myJSFunction()
{
    myFlashObject.asFunc("Hello!");
}

function calc(s)
{
    // ...
}
```

... your corresponding ActionScript 3 code should look something more like this:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface; 

function myInitializationHandler():void
{   
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("asFunc", asFunc); 
    myFlexButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener); 
}

function asFunc(str:String):void 
{ 
    //... 
}

function clickListener(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    // ...
    ExternalInterface.call("calc", myFlexTextInput.text); 
}
```

Make sense?